# Jest - React - Testing the component that retrieves data from the API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I would like to test my component appears. The component accepts a props id, then performs an API request and when it receives the data, it renders a structure for us. I want to check if this structure has been rendered.

I get this error after running the test:

```
  received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
    Received has value: null
```

Does it have to do with asynchrony? Maybe I need to somehow mark that I have to wait for this component to do something and then check if it exists?

```js
it('Some test', () => {
  const { container } = render(<SomeComponent id={1} />);
  const element = container.querySelector("someTag");
  expect(element).toBeVisible();
});
```

SomeComponent looks like:

```js
const Somecomponent = ({ id }: Props) => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError, refetch } = someFunction(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [id]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <ErrorContent />;
  }

  if (!video) {
    return <InfoContent />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AnotherComponent {...data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default SomeComponent;
```

And of course in AnotherComponent we have logic to display some content based on data

Comment: It's really difficult to answer your questions when you don't post your code.

Comment: @possum I updated

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using react-testing-library, so you can use the [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) method (or any [findBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#findby-queries) method).

```
it('Some test', async() => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<SomeComponent id={1} />);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByTestId('some test id')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: I did     
<div data-testid="custom-element">
      <AnotherComponent {...data} />
</div>
And i got error:
    Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="custom-element"]

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example?